# Change the URL to URL with HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

I have my `.htacces` on my server and it looks like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But when I type `example.com` in my browser it doesn't redirect to `https://example.com`. How can I do that?

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: What does it do? Is `.htaccess` / mod_rewrite enabled? Is `FollowSymLinks` enabled? Any other directives? Any other `.htaccess` files? Using a CDN? Proxy servers? Cleared cache (as starkeen suggests)? There's nothing actually wrong with the directives you have posted - so it could be "something else".

Comment: @w3dk how can I enable mod_rewrite? The .htacces is all you see there. I dont really know how to use .htacces

Comment: Just try adding some "nonsense" to the start of your `.htaccess` file - do you get an error? Do you have access to the server? Try adding `Options +FollowSymLinks` to the start of the file.

Comment: Also, `.htaccess` has 2 `s` - you have referred to it with just 1 `s`?!

Comment: @w3dk that was the problem. I wrote .htaccess wrong. but thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem it was just the spelling of `.htaccess` (filename) that was the problem. This has two `s`, not one, as stated in the question.

Bit of an aside... the name of this file (per-directory Apache config filename) can be changed in the server config (although this is rare):

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```