# How to redirect .htacces to another alias

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How to remove only "-home" from URL?

From:

`https://www.example.com/arbipedia-comentarios-a-lei-de-arbitragem-home/conteudo-exclusivo-arbipedia/1314.html`

to:

`https://www.example.com/arbipedia-comentarios-a-lei-de-arbitragem/conteudo-exclusivo-arbipedia/1314.html`

Comment: [Note that `.htaccess` has two `s`!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43308525/change-the-url-to-url-with-https)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following redirect to remove **-home** substring from uri :

```
RedirectMatch ^/(.+)-home/(.+)$ /$1/$2
```

This will redirect http://example.com/foo-home/bar to http://example.com/foo/bar .